# Give Error and Exit when no Keyboard Input is Provided

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, keyboard-input

A rookie here! This is a very simple one. 
I am trying to write a script that asks for user inputs.
Then *read* the inputs and do some stuff with it.
But I first want to make sure inputs are provided.

Example:

```
echo "Please provide input1:"
read Input1
echo "Please provide input2:"
read Input2

if [ -z "$Input1" ]
echo "You did not provide input1"
exit
else if [ -z "$Input2" ]
echo "You did not provide input2"
exit 
fi
```

However the above doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work while making it look more readable? Is there a better simpler way?

Comment: `Input1` is a literal string, you want to reference the variable. Use `"$Input1"`.

Comment: So by "doesn't work" you mean you get a syntax error? You should have said that and included the syntax error in your post.

Comment: Yes, @glennjackman elif is what I needed. But is there a better way? I don't like to have this chunk of code in middle of the script. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: A better way to do what? Test those two variables for having a value? No. You need to test them somewhere. You could use command line arguments and `getopts` but that only changes what reports failure if you leave the arguments off (and you still need to check for empty strings).

Comment: hm, I see. Thanks @EtanReisner I will leave it as it is with the if-statement included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `elif` not `else if`, and you are missing the mandatory `then` keywords: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

```
read -p "Please provide input1: " Input1
read -p "Please provide input2: " Input2

if [ -z "$Input1" ]; then
    echo "You did not provide input1"
    exit
elif [ -z "$Input2" ]; then
    echo "You did not provide input2"
    exit 
fi
```

If, instead of exiting, you want to provide a default value, you can do:

```
read -p "Please provide input1: " Input1
read -p "Please provide input2: " Input2
: ${Input1:=first default value}
: ${Input2:=second default value}
echo "Input1: $Input1"
echo "Input2: $Input2"
```